# How do I pass data with my MEAN app? From a page of products to a new page with details about the specific product that the user clicked on?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a newbie at the `MEAN stack`. I have a full app working and have searched extensively on how to solve the following problem but I'm realizing that I don't know how to "ask" the question to be sent to the proper resource.

I have a `marketplace`. In the dashboard, a user can enter details about their product (a boat) and it is sent to the DB. In my `marketplace`, I'm retrieving all of the boats from the DB and theyre styled and listed on the page.

I want a user to click on one of the tiles components that I have created with an `ng-list` (boat) and be sent to a new page with a fully-expanded view of that specific boat. (larger pictures, expanded details, etc.) basically all the details about the product that won't fit in the minimalistic tile component in the marketplace.

How do I pass data about that specific boat that the user clicks on and be sent to a new page? Is this an `ng-directive`? an API/route thing?

I just am unsure how to reference the specific boat from the list i'm retrieving and have the user sent to a new details page. Any direction or resources that will teach me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, use `ng-repeat` to display a list of products and `ng-click` to handle clicks.

```
<a ng-repeat="product in productList" ng-click="goto($index)">
    <h2> {{product.title}}</h2>
    <img ng-src="{{product.picture}}">
    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.goto = function(index) {
    $location(productList[index].location);
});
```

Use a router such as `ngRoute` or `ui-route` to intercept the new location and load the appropriate template and controller.